# Multiple interface declarations of different types in one file

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add in multiple interface declarations, but not getting very far. I think I may be getting the syntax wrong, but I've tried it a few times and it's shifting me through error message after error message. Here's the contents of the header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AGDWTiledImageView : UIView

- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame tileset: (NSString *)tileset;

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The code that throws up the error message is the last line of

```
for (int row = firstRow; row <= lastRow; row++) {
        for (int col = firstCol; col <= lastCol; col++) {
            UIImage *tile;
            UIImage *rotatedImage = [tile imageRotatedByDegrees:270.0];
```

The error message says "no visible @interface for UIImage declares the selector imageRotatedByDegrees"

Comment: What is the error message?  What line is the error message attached to?  Is that the entire contents of the header file?

Comment: the error message comes when I try to use imageRotatedByDegrees, and says "no visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector imageRotatedByDegrees"

Comment: Update your question to include the code that tries to use `imageRotatedByDegrees`.

Comment: done. the only line I've added since the last working build are the ones that refer to imageRotatedByDegrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code from your question makes no sense:

```
        UIImage *tile;
        UIImage *rotatedImage = [tile imageRotatedByDegrees:270.0];
```

So first you declare `tile` as a pointer to a `UIImage`.  Since you don't explicitly give it a value, it's initialized to `nil`.  You probably want to point it at some actual instance of `UIImage`, but I don't know what image you want it to point to.

Then you try to send it the `imageRotatedByDegrees:` message.  But that message isn't declared for `UIImage`.  It's declared only for `AGDWTiledImageView`.

If you want `UIImage` to understand a message named `imageRotatedByDegrees:`, you can declare a *category* on `UIImage`.  It's better to put a prefix on your category selectors to avoid conflicts with other categories or with Apple's future extensions to the class.  (A selector is a message/method name.)

```
// UIImage+AGDW.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (AGDW)

- (UIImage *)AGDW_imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees;

@end

// UIImage+AGDW.m

@implementation UIImage (AGDW)

- (UIImage *)AGDW_imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    // your implementation here
}
```

Then, at the top of the file where you want to use `AGDW_imageRotatedByDegrees:`, you must `#import "UIImage+AGDW.h"`.

Comment: thanks. I was aware about initialising to nil, I was more concerned with getting it to compile. I'll have a look and see what this can do for me.